# How do I fix editor scroll lag in Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started using Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) on Windows 10. The editor is lagging when I scroll up and down using the up/down arrow keys. In other words, when I move the caret vertically outside the view, the text doesn't scroll smoothly. But the line numbers scroll smoothly. The lag is less with plain text than Java files. I tried turning spell check off, but that didn't help.

**Problem solved:** The scroll lag disappeared recently, and the editor is working smoother than ever. I think this happened after I got a notification in Eclipse saying that updates were available, and I clicked the notification and did the updates.

Comment: It's an internal IDE bug you can't do much about it. You can either update or change the IDE

Comment: Check your CPU and RAM usage. If that does not help create a detailed report in the Eclipse bug tracker.

Comment: Upgrade CPU and RAM.

Comment: I have a 1.9 MHz processor with two cores and 4 GB RAM. Neon is also slow.

Comment: I have the same problem for Python. CPU and RAM  not  the issue (12GB & 2.8 GHz)

Comment: Perhaps this describes the problem?https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530446

Comment: Yes, it seems that bug 530446 is the same thing. I think they might have fixed it, because the scroll lag disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Found one culprit: **the mouse!**

Having a "*gamer*" mouse (mine is a Logitech G502) that send mouse position at the rate of 1000 Hz have a **strong** impact on Eclipse vertical scrolling lag.

- Lowering the mouse rate to 500 Hz reduce the lag but do not eliminate it.
- Lowering the mouse rate to 250 Hz practically eliminate the lag.

This is really a problem specific to Eclipse, because I have tested with WebStorm and IntelliJ and neither of them manifest any lag while scrolling the same test file.